# Service Broker Connection handshake failed. There is no compatible encryption algorithm

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

My target server is not receiving the message and the following error shows in the target servers error logs. Service Broker login attempt failed with error: 'Connection handshake failed. There is no compatible encryption algorithm. State 22.'

I am using service broker transport security - certificate based authentication.
My master db keys and certs are set, permissions are granted to broker_endpoint.
My user db keys and certs are set, permissions are granted to services.

My Endpoints on each server are configured for certificates, have permission to the master db cert, and all my databases are authenticated by the same user.

I am also receiving an error in Sql Trace, on target server: Certificate Not Found.

The problem here is that the service that it is documenting on the same row, in sql trace, is for a different service broker configured on the source server that I didn't reference in my conversations.

When I view sys.certificates, on both servers,  all certs are tied to the proper issuer_name.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service broker instance on another server was causing this error. It didn't have a master certificate on the server with error.

I dropped the service broker instance on the other server and the error went away.

Comment: Would you consider fleshing out your answer slightly and marking the answer as accepted? This would help the community. Thanks.